# How do I get my app to show up in the "Open In..." popover list in the iPad?

Tags: ipad, plist, documents

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I associate file types with an iPhone application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2774343/how-do-i-associate-file-types-with-an-iphone-application)

After some Googling, I found I was to change my plist file to include "Document Types" ---> an array with two values in each spot: Document Type Name, Handler Rank.

I did this and wrote public.pdf, public.png, etc... as the document type names and I tried every available handler rank.  However, when I test it on the iPad, my app still will not display in the "Open in..." list.

Can anyone help me to achieve this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I have not tested, but does this work for you?

Also see the following link: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/understanding_utis/understand_utis_declare/understand_utis_declare.html

```
<key>CFBundleDocumentTypes</key>
<array>
    <dict>
        <key>CFBundleTypeExtensions</key>
        <array>
            <string>pdf</string>
        </array>
        <key>CFBundleTypeIconFile</key>
        <string>app.icns</string>
        <key>CFBundleTypeName</key>
        <string>public.pdf</string>
        <key>CFBundleTypeRole</key>
        <string>Editor</string>
        <key>LSHandlerRank</key>
        <string>Alternate</string>
        <key>LSItemContentTypes</key>
        <array>
            <string>public.pdf</string>
        </array>
    </dict>
    <dict>
        <key>CFBundleTypeExtensions</key>
        <array>
            <string>png</string>
        </array>
        <key>CFBundleTypeIconFile</key>
        <string>app.icns</string>
        <key>CFBundleTypeName</key>
        <string>public.png</string>
        <key>CFBundleTypeRole</key>
        <string>Editor</string>
        <key>LSHandlerRank</key>
        <string>Alternate</string>
        <key>LSItemContentTypes</key>
        <array>
            <string>public.png</string>
        </array>
    </dict>
</array>
```

and this...

```
<key>UTImportedTypeDeclarations</key>
<array>
    <dict>
        <key>UTTypeConformsTo</key>
        <array>
            <string>public.data</string>
        </array>
        <key>UTTypeIdentifier</key>
        <string>public.pdf</string>
        <key>UTTypeTagSpecification</key>
        <dict>
            <key>com.apple.ostype</key>
            <string>PDF</string>
            <key>public.filename-extension</key>
            <array>
                <string>pdf</string>
            </array>
            <key>public.mime-type</key>
            <string>application/pdf</string>
        </dict>
    </dict>
    <dict>
        <key>UTTypeConformsTo</key>
        <array>
            <string>public.image</string>
        </array>
        <key>UTTypeIdentifier</key>
        <string>public.png</string>
        <key>UTTypeTagSpecification</key>
        <dict>
            <key>com.apple.ostype</key>
            <string>PNG</string>
            <key>public.filename-extension</key>
            <array>
                <string>png</string>
            </array>
            <key>public.mime-type</key>
            <string>image/png</string>
        </dict>
    </dict>
</array>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! - I'll give it a shot but where did you put this code?

Comment: Open your .plist file in a text editor (such as TextWrangler) and paste it in place of your existing `<key>CFBundleDocumentTypes</key>` and the `<array> ... </array>` immediately following it. Figured it would be easier to than trying to use the interface in Xcode.

Comment: It is telling me that the file has been corrupted and it can not read it...

Comment: Sorry, that's because I missed a `</dict>` there in the middle. Just recopy the code.

Comment: I recopied the code - and no error anymore - thats slick by the way, didn't know you could do it in text editor but... still not in the popup list...

Comment: I added a second block of code you should add after what you have already, as well as a link to some Apple documentation which may be helpful. Sorry I can't test this out before posting but I don't have the necessary equipment. Hopefully in the end this can at least help you along the way a little. :)

Comment: THAT WAS AWESOME!  Thanks so much! Its in the menu, just as I had hoped.  You saved the day

Comment: Glad to have helped! Best of luck with your app.

Comment: I have tried all the methodology provided here and other places as well, but I am still struggling to get open PNG files. I am working with iOS 7. In some places they are saying that this problem starts with ios 6. Is it true? Can't we open png files in "Open in " dialog box with ios 7?