# ios : Changes in info.plist for opening file types like doc and pdf

Tags: iphone, ios, document

I am a newbie to ios,there is a requirement in my app to support showing and opening up of file types like doc,pdf when requested in other app like dropbox. I read Apple's documentation and it says adding a row "Document types" in info.plist. But i am not sure what values i have  to put in there if its for doc ,pdf.

I am not sure either if this is the right the approach i have to follow .

Comment: E.g. http://stackoverflow.com/a/6397106/1691231 has answers that contain the necessary code for opening PDFs in your app.

Answer (score 0):

Add following dict to info plist for opening file types like doc and pdf

------------- For PDF ----------------------

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>CFBundleTypeIconFiles</key>
    <array>
        <string>PDFIcon64.png</string>
        <string>PDFIcon320.png</string>
    </array>
    <key>CFBundleTypeName</key>
    <string>PDF</string>
    <key>LSHandlerRank</key>
    <string>Default</string>
    <key>LSItemContentTypes</key>
    <array>
        <string>com.adobe.pdf</string>
    </array>
</dict>
</plist>
```

------- For DOC -----------

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>CFBundleTypeIconFiles</key>
    <array>
        <string>PDFIcon64.png</string>
        <string>PDFIcon320.png</string>
    </array>
    <key>CFBundleTypeName</key>
    <string>DOC</string>
    <key>LSHandlerRank</key>
    <string>Default</string>
    <key>LSItemContentTypes</key>
    <array>
        <string>com.microsoft.word.doc</string>
        <string>org.openxmlformats.wordprocessingml.document</string>
        <string>org.openxmlformats.wordprocessingml.document.macroenabled</string>
    </array>
</dict>
</plist>
```