# How do I get my app to show up in the “Open In…” List on iPhone?

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch

I've found this link to use Document Types in the info.plist

[How do I get my app to show up in the "Open In..." popover list in the iPad?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6397052/how-do-i-get-my-app-to-show-up-in-the-open-in-popover-list-in-the-ipad)

but what if I want to add any kind of file to the Document types, shoud I add "jpg,png,pdf,mov,xml,php,doc,ppt....." to the info.plist.

Is there a easy way to make myapp open any kind of file in another app?

Comment: this will help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7942597/supporting-open-in-menu-item-in-my-app-for-ios-mail-and-safari

Answer (score 0):

usually we will write Open in actionsheet and on clicking that we will call the documentationinteraction controller to find the applicable apps which can open the document

```
UIDocumentInteractionController *docInteractionController = [UIDocumentInteractionController interactionControllerWithURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:@"file_full_path.pdf"]];

[docInteractionController presentOptionsMenuFromRect:self.view.frame
                                                   inView:self.view
                                                 animated:YES];
```

fileURLWithPath:- contains the file name of full path

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but you do not understand my question. I want myapp show in another app's "open in" list, not let other app show  in myapp's "open in" list.