# iOS - Can't get "Open in" to include my app

Tags: ios, import, plist, documents

I've read several resources online, and I must just be missing something simple. I've reviewed the apple documentation on Uniform Type Identifiers, and I've read through forum posts as well, and I don't see what I'm doing incorrectly.

This is from my Info.plist file:

```
<key>CFBundleDocumentTypes</key>
<array>
    <dict>
        <key>CFBundleTypeName</key>
        <string>kUTTypePNG</string>
        <key>LSHandlerRank</key>
        <string>Alternate</string>
        <key>LSItemContentType</key>
        <array>
            <string>public.png</string>
        </array>
    </dict>
    <dict>
        <key>CFBundleTypeName</key>
        <string>PDF</string>
        <key>CFBundleTypeRole</key>
        <string>Editor</string>
        <key>LSHandlerRank</key>
        <string>Alternate</string>
        <key>LSItemContentType</key>
        <array>
            <string>com.adobe.pdf</string>
        </array>
    </dict>
</array>
```

As you can see, I've tried various combinations of the keys, such as leaving out CFBundleTypeRole, using the constant name ("kUTTypePNG", which doesn't seem right, but I saw it in another post), etc, and no luck.

Note that this is importing only. I'm not trying to export any custom file types.

Are there any other requirements other than adding this to my plist?

Am I missing some keys or using incorrect information?

Comment: Assuming you're sending mail with the attachments to an account you see on your device, try viewing the message source on a computer and see if the mime headers are what you expect.

Comment: @DavidH I'll check that. I am assuming they are correct on the file, as it provides options to open in other 3rd party apps, but may as well make sure.

Comment: If the mime is correct and you did your plist correctly, then users should have the option of using your app to open each of these.

Comment: @DavidH, That's what I'm asking for help on. Does the code above (taken from my plist) look correct? Am I missing anything? I checked the message contents, and they are correct: "image/png" and "application/pdf". Additionally, I tried sending one of my photos from my camera roll, and still my app doesn't show up. So it seems like a problem with registering the file type. Just don't know how I should change my plist.

Comment: Found that this solution works...http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6397052/how-do-i-get-my-app-to-show-up-in-the-open-in-popover-list-in-the-ipad

Comment: I have tried all the methodology provided here and other places as well, but I am still struggling to get open PNG files. I am working with iOS 7. In some places they are saying that this problem starts with ios 6. Is it true? Can't we open png files in "Open in " dialog box with ios 7?